# Use a tethered PC as a gateway to WAN while allowing the same PC access to the LAN

Tags: routing, linux-networking, local-area-network, bridge

Some background to understand my question:

I have no fixed internet connection at home. Only internet access is through my mobile phone. I tether my mobile to whichever device needs internet access and this works fine for me.

However, some devices require a LAN to operate properly, so I've been trying to set up various routers I've acquired over the years to provide a WiFi network that has no internet access until my phone is added into the network.

I don't mind if I need to have my linux PC turned on and tethered to provide internet to the LAN, but I need the LAN to operate (albeit without internet access) without my PC turned on.

In the following examples, my LAN shall always have address 192.168.1.0/24
and my router (wireless access point with eth LAN ports and one WAN port) has LAN address 192.168.1.1. When I tether my phone to my PC, usb0 interface is automatically configured.

What I've gotten working:

**Scenario A**:

- connect eth0 of linux PC to LAN port of router
- configure eth0 with static IP 192.168.1.100
- disable DHCP on router, and enable DHCP relay to 192.168.1.100
- run dnsmasq on linux PC on eth0
- enable forwarding in iptables

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o usb0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Effect of Scenario A**:

- PC off: LAN does not operate at all
- PC on, without phone tethered: LAN operates normally without internet access
- PC on, with phone tethered: LAN operates normally with internet access

**Scenario B**:

- connect eth0 of linux PC to WAN port of router
- WAN port configured to use DHCP
- WAN port configured with NAT **disabled**
- enable DHCP server for LAN of router
- bridge eth0 and usb0 together

**Effect of scenario B**:

- PC off: LAN operates normally without internet access
- PC on, without phone tethered: LAN operates normally without internet access, but PC has no LAN access
- PC on, with phone tethered: LAN has internet access, but PC has no LAN access

**Scenario C**:

- using usb to eth cable, connect phone to router WAN port
- WAN port configured to use DHCP
- WAN port configured with NAT **enabeld**
- enable DHCP server on router LAN

Scenario A is good because my PC has access to the LAN as I definitely **require**. The problem is that my PC has to be on for any device to connect to the LAN as my PC runs the DHCP server.

Scenario B is good because my PC doesn't have to be on for devices to connect to the LAN, and when my PC is turned on with my phone tethered, all devices on the LAN have internet access. However, my PC has no access to the LAN.

Scenario C is **untested** - but given how scenario B just worked (WAN got IP via DHCP server on phone), I'm pretty sure this works.

I'd really like something like scenario B to work, since I ought to be able to configure my linux PC to do just about anything. I'd like to learn more about routing with linux, so I'd actually prefer to put the effort into figuring out how to do this with what I have.

**My vision**:

```
Phone <-------> [usb0]PC[eth0] <-------> [WAN]Router[LAN] <-------> Devices
   192.168.X.0/24           192.168.100.0/24            192.168.1.0/24
```

I want the router configuration to be as minimal as possible (no special routes or anything), so that it could be swapped out for an arbitrary router. The PC can be as complicated routing setup as is necessary.
**My PC has only one NIC.**

**Question**: How can I achieve this with my current hardware?

I'm running MXLinux 18.3 which is Debian based.

Comment: Home networking questions are expressly off topic for Server fault, however, you may ask them on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your scenario C will work but since you prefer to learn linux configuration then I think it's a good idea.

My way of doing this would be:

1. Set up your Linux PC to get Internet access from your phone
2. Set static IP for Linux PC - for example 192.168.0.1
3. Connect Linux PC and all others to LAN ports on your router
4. Set static IP for you router - fe. 192.168.0.2
5. Set your router as a bridge if possible or access point.
6. Enable DHCP on your router and set "gateway" as 192.168.0.1 (to point at your Linux PC).
7. Configure your PC to act as a gateway (you'll have to figure it out yourself)

At this point every device that will connect wirelessly or via ether to your LAN will see all other devices because it will get an IP from your router and no matter if your PC will be on or off - LAN will be working - just no Internet (cause PC acting as a gateway is off)
And when your PC will be working it will have Internet access via phone and LAN access via eth0.

If your PC will be configured as a gateway then when it will be on it will be reachable for other devices and they will be able to communicate with Internet.

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll try it out. Pretty sure I have the knowledge I need to do it.